# Unable to Update Yes/No Field in document library within ApplicationPage Code-Behind

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, application-pages, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to read the value within my CustomApplicationPage.aspx.cs file and update the value from `No` to `Yes`.By default when this site column was created in the Content Type Hub's custom content type, its value is set as `No`.In my code am doing some manipulation and have to set this value to `Yes`.But unfortunately I am not able to get the value of this Yes/No column-checkbox and update it.Here is my code.

```
      item = list.Items.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(stritemid));
       LogFile("after calling getitembyid in page load"," getitembyid 
       stack trace in item==","page load_aftr_getting item"+ item.Title);
        spWebobj.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
          documentName = item.Name;
           documentUrl = item.Url;
            if (item != null && item.Fields["CMPDocument"] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                    {
                        SPFieldBoolean blnCMPDocumentField = 
                  item.Fields["CMPDocument"] as SPFieldBoolean;
                 bool cmpDocumentValue =                               
           (bool)blnCMPDocumentField.GetFieldValue(item["CMPDocument"]
             .ToString());
                        item["CMPDocument"] = true;
                        item.Update();
                        item.ParentList.Update();
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    PortalLog.LogString("Error in Updating the 
             CMPDocument column in current item  " + item.Name + " and 
                its URL " + item.Url.ToString() + ");
                }
```

Want to know whether the code item["cmpdocument"] =true is the correct way of updating a yes/no field.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
item = list.Items.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(stritemid));      
try
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        using(SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPListItem elevatedItem = item.ParentList.GetItemById(item.ID);
                if(elevatedItem.File.CheckOutType == SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None)
                {
                    elevatedItem.File.CheckOut();
                }
                else
                {
                    elevatedItem.File.CheckIn(string.Empty);
                    elevatedItem.File.CheckOut();
                }
                item["CMPDocument"] = "1";
                item.Update();
            }
        }       
    });
}
catch (Exception)
{
    PortalLog.LogString("Error in Updating the 
CMPDocument column in current item  " + item.Name + " and 
its URL " + item.Url.ToString() + ");
}
```

You don't need to update the list for updating an item. And also you should open the `SPSite` and `SPWeb` objects under `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` and fetch `SPListItem` if you want to update by the System Account in code snippet.

Comment: am  geteting the error :he file "http://srvr1:123/sites/ConDnC/mydoclib/ForTestingPurpose-Copy1.txt" is checked out for editing by i:0#.w|in\user_abcd._error in udating the cmpdocument column<br/>
StackTrace :The file "http://srvr1:123/sites/ConDnC/mydoclib/ForTestingPurpose-Copy1.txt" is checked out for editing by i:0#.w|in\myuser1._error in udating the cmpdocument column
Date :6/12/2015 5:04:03 PM__error in item.update call

Comment: Try updated code.